does c++ short circuit evaluation cause jumps and CPU-pipeline-flushes?
AFAIK c++ guarantees that in a expression a-expr && b-expr b-expr is not evaluated if a-expr is false. (Similar is true for or-expressions)
does that mean that there will be a jump in the generated code that will flush the cpu-pipeline?
Or how can/is this be prevented?
what if the expressions are so simple that stupiditly calculating all the results would be faster than the short-circuit? Can this be detected/exploited by compilers?
Or do the programmer have to seperate all the expressions into single variable assignments and maybe use bitwise instead logic operators to prevent such jumps?

Compiler operates under the as-if rule. It can do anything with the code as long as the observable behaviour stays the same. Do not worry about compiler optimisation unless you 1) find out that your program doesn't meet speed requirements and 2) profile your code and find the bool evaluation to be the bottleneck in your program.

Branches don't "flush the pipeline" to begin, not even when mispredicted (which is really the concern and can have a significant cost, but it's not "flush the pipeline"), not on relevant processor anyway

are you worried that there might be scenarios where bool a = a-expr; bool b = b-expr; bool c= a-expr && b-expr; performs better than bool c = a-expr && b-expr; ? Suppose there was, then I'd expect compiler writers to know about it too. In any case you shouldnt write your code with such microoptimizations in mind

Compilers can convert && to & and || to | on bool when the cost of the branch and the possible branch misprediction is greater than the cost of doing the "wasted" computation on any modern hardware, this is only done when the compiler can tell that evaluating the "wasted" branch has no side-effect. (following the As-If rule).
take the following two functions
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 1 & b == 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int bar(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 1 && b == 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

Both gcc and clang produce the same code for both functions at -O1 which doesn't include a branch , while MSVC seems to still produce a branch even at O2 godbolt demo
this optimization is only possible if the compiler can verify that this operation has no side-effect, if you are calling a library function that isn't inlined then this optimization might not happen, in which case it would make sense to either inline small functions in the header, or manually use bitwise operations instead of logical operations.

The easiest way for the compiler to avoid evaluating b-expr is to use conditional instructions other that branches. E.g. CMOV is a "conditional move" on x86. Classic ARM has conditional variants of pretty much every instruction.
But as you correctly note, evaluating b-expr can also be a valid approach. Compilers do know what happens as a side-effect of the evaluation of b-expr and might see that those effects are absent or harmless.
Modern CPU's have pretty good branch predictors, which means that simple branches like this aren't as costly as they used to be.

but a conditional move still requires the argument to be calculated beforehand. It can just help to eliminate a required jump on a conditional assignment, and can not elliminate the calculation of the condition

@vlad_tepesch: CPU cycles are quite cheap, memory access often is the slower operation.

The C Or C++ standards don’t guarantee the second expression is not evaluated, they guarantee that you won’t be able to detect the difference.
For example, if it is guaranteed that the second expression has no visible side effects if the first is false, then both can be evaluated. Or parts that have no side effects could be evaluated. if (x > 0 && a[i++] == 1) can evaluate a[i] but must only increase i if x > 0 is true (if i is guaranteed to be a valid index).
For simple expressions evaluating both is sometimes legal and sometimes faster, and good compilers will do it in those cases. If a conditional branch is needed, current processors have a lot of hardware used to reduce the cost, often to zero.
Summary: There is no reason whatsoever to avoid && and || in your source code.
